# Angular 1.x/2 Hybrid, karma tests not bootstrapping ng1 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular2-upgrade

I currently have a Hybrid Angular app (2.4.9 and 1.5.0) using angular-cli. Currently, when running our application, we are able to bootstrap the 1.5 app correctly:

```js
// main.ts
import ...

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  angular.element(document).ready(() => { 
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp'], {strictDi: true});
  });
});
```

However, in our `test.ts` file:

```js
// test.ts
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import ...;

declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

__karma__.loaded = function () {};

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  // I'm assuming that I need to call 'boostrapModule()' somehow here...
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting() 
);

const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

context.keys().map(context);

__karma__.start();
```

I'm not exactly sure how to bootstrap our 1.5 application into the test environment, all I've gotten is `Module 'myApp' is not available!`, and my Google skills have failed trying to find an example.

Comment: Might be good to remove `declare var __karma__: any;` and use the actual `@types/karma` package. This is not causing your error, but every `declare const lib: any;` in your code is throwing away tooling that is often helpful.

Comment: I must admit, when I read "Angular 1.x/2 Hybrid", I was in disbelief that such a thing was even possible.

Answer (score 7):

I was hoping the bounty I added last night would mean I could log on this morning to a nice solution laid out for me. Alas, it did not. So instead I spent the day cruising around many SO answers and github issues getting it to work. I'm sorry I did not keep track of everything that helped me to credit them, but here is my solution. It is probably not ideal, but it is working so far so I hope it is a good start.

[This github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14263) indicates that `downgradeComponent` isn't going to work for now, so I went with what I assume is an older technique using `UpgradeAdapter`. Note that this technique does not use `initTestEnvironment`. Here are the relevant snippets, with some explanations below:

```
// downgrade.ts:
export const componentsToDowngrade = {
    heroDetail: HeroDetailComponent,
    ...
};
export function downgradeForApp() {
    forOwn(componentsToDowngrade, (component, name) => {
        app.directive(name!, downgradeComponent({ component }));
    });
}


// main.ts:
downgradeForApp();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory).then((platformRef) => {
    ...
});

// test.ts:
require("../src/polyfills.ts");
require("zone.js/dist/proxy");
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require("zone.js/dist/mocha-patch");

// test-helper.ts
let upgradeAdapterRef: UpgradeAdapterRef;
const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(AppModule);
forEach(componentsToDowngrade, (component, selectorName) => {
    angular.module("app").directive(
        selectorName!,
        upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(component) as any,
    );
});
export function useAdaptedModule() {
    beforeEach(() => {
        upgradeAdapterRef = upgradeAdapter.registerForNg1Tests(["app"]);
    });
}
export function it(expectation: string, callback: () => void) {
    test(expectation, (done) => {
        inject(() => { }); // triggers some kind of needed initialization
        upgradeAdapterRef.ready(() => {
            try {
                callback();
                done();
            } catch (ex) { done(ex); }
        });
    });
}


// hero-detail.component.spec.ts
import { it, useAdaptedModule } from "test-helpers/sd-app-helpers";
describe("", () => {
    useAdaptedModule();
    it("behaves as expected", () => { ... });
});
```

A few of the highlights from that code:

- I downgrade components differently for tests than for the app, so I made a DRY list of them in `downgrade.ts`
- I downgrade components for the main app from `main.ts` by calling `downgradeForApp()` as shown above (used with AOT for a production bundle), and also `main-jit.ts`, not shown above (used for development)
- I showed the imports I needed to add to start integrating Angular components into my AngularJS tests. You may need more/different ones depending e.g. on whether your tests are asynchronous, or you use Jasmine instead of Mocha.
- At the beginning of each test that needs to use downgraded components, I "bootstrap" things with `useAdaptedModule()` instead of `beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));`
- I import an alternative `it` from my helpers, which wraps the `it` provided by Mocha. None of my tests are asynchronous; if you have some that are it may require tweaking. I do not know how it may need to be adapted for Jasmine.

**A caveat:** Instantiating the component must happen within an `it` callback so that it happens within `upgradeAdapterRef.ready(...)`. Trying to do it within a `beforeEach` is too soon.